# Windows Phone Pivot and Blend

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot, mvvm-light, datatemplateselector

I am trying to design a `Pivot Page` on Windows Phone, each Pivot Item would have a different template. I am using MVVM Light and in the `ViewModelLocator` I want to have a property 
`List<ViewModelBase>` (or another Base class with some common properties for my PivotItems ViewModels) and bind it to the ItemsSource property of my Pivot. I also want to use a `DataTemplateSelector` so I can choose between the DataTemplates for each Pivot. The DataTemplates I am storing them in a `ResourceDictionary`.

The problem is that for some reason, I can't see my `desing-data` in Blend, what I mean is that I can't play around with each PivotItem and work on it's template.

If I would add the `PivotItems` manually, and I would set the `DataContext` of each of them to my particular `ViewModelBase subclass`, then it would work, and I also wouldn't have to work with the `DataTemplateSelector` as I would be able to set the DataTemplate manually from Blend to each PivotItem.

I am trying to do all this, because I want to change the `DataTemplate of the PivotHeader`, but I can't manage to bind it, as I can't select the DataContext, so if I would use a `List<ViewModelBase>` to bind with the ItemsSource, then when I would try to edit the HeaderDataTemplate, the DataContext in the HeaderTemplate would already be set to ViewModelBase (or whatever Base I would use to derive the ViewModels for each PivotItem).

I am using `Visual Studio 2010 Express` and `Microsoft Expression` Blend 4.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a specific question in there somewhere? Or just a how can I do it?

Comment: It's actually more of a how can I do it question. I am looking for a suggestion, a best MVVM approach for working with Pivot control.